# How grunt plugin get initialized?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I have understood the concept of "require" and "module.export". Now as per my understanding if one file is exporting a module another file invoking that by using "require".

Now in writing grunt task , we write

```
module.exports = function(grunt){}
```

Now who requires the module and how grunt argument is passed? I mean how does it work?

Also if some one can tell me what is the life cycle of a node plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Basically grunt is doing the require and than calling that exported function with its instance of grunt.
you can see it in: [task.js](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/a09f84c8aedfc87cbf357b1ac45b7b70571e954f/lib/grunt/task.js#L312-L316)

```
// Load taskfile.
fn = require(path.resolve(filepath));
if (typeof fn === 'function') {
  fn.call(grunt, grunt);
}
```